# How to find all downloaded items information?

Tags: android

I am developing one application related to downloads.

For that i am searching.I got some examples,but these examples are not full fill my
requirement.

My requirement is getting the information about all downloaded items.

If any one know the solution,please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> My requirement is getting the information about all downloaded items.

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Applications do not have to somehow magically make their Internet operations available for you to spy upon.